# LogIn with FaceBook API from PHP doens't work

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to make a LogIn or register with `Facebook` from my web but doesn't work, actually some weeks back that work but since the last week it doesn't change the status from the API

in the father file (for give it that name) bucause I'm using `MVC` with `PHP`I declare ths script like this

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '300012410734892',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.0'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and in the JS file where I send the data to the controller, i make all of this

```
/*=============================================
FACEBOOK Button
=============================================*/

$(".facebook").click(function(){

    FB.login(function(response){

        validateUser();

    }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'})

})

/*=============================================
Validate the login
=============================================*/

function validateUser(){

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

        statusChangeCallback(response);

    })

}

/*=============================================
VALIDATE THE CHANG OF STATUS IN FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

function statusChangeCallback(response){

    if(response.status === 'connected'){

        testApi();

    }else{
        console.log("response", response);
        swal({
          title: "¡ERROR!",
          text: "¡There was an error logging in with Facebook, try again!",
          type: "error",
          confirmButtonText: "Close",
          closeOnConfirm: false
        },

        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {    
                window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
            } 
        });

    }

}

/*=============================================
API FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

function testApi(){

    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture',function(response){

        if(response.email == null){

            swal({
              title: "¡ERROR!",
              text: "¡To enter the system you must provide the email information!",
              type: "error",
              confirmButtonText: "Close",
              closeOnConfirm: false
            },

            function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {    
                    window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
                } 
            });

        }else{

            var email = response.email;
            var name= response.name;
            var picture= "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture?type=large";

            var datos = new FormData();
            datos.append("email", email);
            datos.append("name",name);
            datos.append("picture",picture);

            $.ajax({

                url:rutaOculta+"ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:datos,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(respuesta){

                    if(respuesta == "ok"){

                        window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");

                    }else{

                        swal({
                          title: "¡ERROR!",
                          text: "¡The email"+email+" is already registered with a different method to Facebook!",
                          type: "error",
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                          closeOnConfirm: false
                        },

                        function(isConfirm){
                            if (isConfirm) {    

                             FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

                                 if(response.status === 'connected'){     

                                    FB.logout(function(response){

                                        deleteCookie("fblo_300012410734892");

                                        setTimeout(function(){

                                            window.location=rutaOculta+"salir";

                                        },500)

                                    });

                                    function deleteCookie(name){

                                         document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

                                    }

                                 }

                             })

                            } 
                        });

                    }

                }

            })

        }

    })

}

/*=============================================
CLOSE SESSION FROM FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

$(".salir").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

         if(response.status === 'connected'){     

            FB.logout(function(response){

                deleteCookie("fblo_300012410734892");

                console.log("salir");

                setTimeout(function(){

                    window.location=rutaOculta+"salir";

                },500)

            });

            function deleteCookie(name){

                 document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

            }

         }

     })

})
```

the problem is that in the `statusChangeCallback`it enter direct to the alert of error and in the console show me this

[image]

Comment: `getLoginStatus` uses cached results, unless specifically instructed otherwise. But the response you get from the login method already contains access token and status, so there is no need to go via that method in the first place - just call `statusChangeCallback` in your `FB.login` callback directly and pass the response in.

Comment: @CBroe I do what yo told me, and the response get a suceess status, but now in the function of `FB.api` the response is empty, I mean `FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture',function(response){` with the `console.log` throw me this message `message: "unknown error (empty response)"`