# FaceBook API JavaScript SDK in FireFox doesn't connect

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using `FireFox` to make the proves with the `FB API` for `JavaScript`, in `Chrome` and `Opera`, and also in `FireFox for Developers` it works, but in the normal `FireFox` it doesn't works and appear this message in the console (i put a `console.log`when enter in the `FB.API`.

to be mor specifically

`FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture',function(response){
        console.log("response", response);`

[image]

Translation:

> Cross-origin request blocked: The same origin policy does not allow the reading of remote resources in URL... (Reason: Unsuccessful CORS request).

why is this problem just in FireFox?

Comment: odd that firefox has a cors error, and you claim firefox developer does not - my guess is you did *something wrong™* - like tag the question with PHP tag for a start

Comment: @jaromandax Well, in fact before adding more code to my application, the registry or login worked correctly, I never touched the code of the connection with Facebook, but it started to fail, my php tag is because I am also working with that language

Comment: Yo could see the code which i'm using in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51509524/login-with-facebook-api-from-php-doenst-work?noredirect=1#comment90076503_51509524

Comment: oh, but your issue is nothing to do with server side, because this is all client side code, so PHP is still irrelevant :p

Comment: @jaromandax oh okok, but, do you see which is the problem at my code? Why only in Firefox doesn't works?

Comment: you say it works in firefox developer edition but not firefox release - which doesn't make sense to me - perhaps you have an addon/extension in one but not the other that causes the difference - or perhaps some setting (tracking protection springs to mind)